# Nhibernate One-To-One mapping by code

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am trying to figure out a way to map one to one relationship in nhibernate when referencing column is not a primary key column on second table.

For example consider

```
Person Table 
   PersonId (pk)
   Name
```

and

```
Passport Table 
   PassportId (pk)
   Country
   PersonId
```

The two tables have one to one relationship on PersonId.

My Nhibernate Model looks like below.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Passport Passport { get; set; }
}

public class Passport
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Based on explanation form [this article](http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one) I defined the relationship mapping as follows but it didn’t work

PersonMapping:

```
OneToOne(x => x.Passport, x => x.Cascade(Cascade.All));
```

PassportMapping:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Person, x => { x.Unique(true); x.Column("PersonId");});
```

it is constructing the sql query as follows

```
select * from Person
left outer join  Passport on Persson.PersonId = Passport.PassportId.
```

it assumes that the PassportId and PersonId has same value but in my case they are different. How can I define my mapping in such case using mapping by code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but I wasted way too much time trying to solve this so I'm adding my solution anyway.

Person mapping:

```
OneToOne(x => x.Passport, m =>
{
    m.Access(Accessor.Property);
    //if you are running an older version of NHibernate like 3.3.4 you might need to do it this way
    //m.PropertyReference(typeof(Passport).GetProperty("Person"));  
    m.PropertyReference(p => p.Person);
    m.Constrained(false);
});
```

Passport mapping:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Person, m =>
{
    m.Column("PersonId")
    m.Unique(true);
    m.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore);
});
```

Comment: Worked for me because database structure was wrong (same case) thank :)

Answer (score -2):

I hope that my post will help you, I will show you how I am doing these kind of mappings:
Mapping for Person:

```
  HasOne(x=>x.Passport).Cascade.All();
```

and the Passport:

```
  References(x => x.Person).Unique();
```

hopes this helps.
Later on, when you want to create a new record do this for example:

```
 var person = new Person();
 person.Passport = new Passport(){Person = person};
```

Comment: This ansver is using fluent nhibernate but the question is for Mapping By Code.